# What is the equivalent of ifort -fixed for the gfortran compiler?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

What is the equivalent of ifort -fixed for the gfortran compiler?  I am trying to link f77 subroutines when I compile my f90 code. This [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342259/how-to-use-fortran-77-subroutines-in-fortran-90-95) post seems to have answered the general question, although I am having trouble finding the equivalent for the gfortran compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-ffixed-form` it took me 10 seconds to google it.